# how to make a popover or select having different options by clicking on column cell in react bootstrap table 2?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

I have a **react-bootstrap-table-next** where I have multiple columns. I want that when I click on edit button in column cell it open up a popover or select with 3 options:

1. Delete
2. Set as Default
3. Edit

here is the image attached.
Could someone please provide me a proper way to do it.
 [3 dots clicked and a list is opened for choices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iA3E3.png)

Here is my code. In the Edit column there is event and onclick listener where I have to render the component.

```
    export const Columns = (callback) => {
          return ([{
        dataField: "code",
        text: "Code",
        sort: true,
        headerStyle: { width: "8%" }
    },
    {
        dataField: "description",
        text: "Description",
        sort: true,
        headerStyle: { width: "40%" }
    },
    {
        dataField: "shortName",
        text: "ShortName",
        sort: true,
        headerStyle: { width: "10%" }
    },
    {
        dataField: "currencyCode",
        text: "Currency",
        sort: true,
        headerStyle: { width: "10%" }
    },
    {
        dataField: "isActive",
        text: "Active/Inactive",
        sort: false,
        formatter: StatusSwitchRenderer,
        headerStyle: { width: "12%" },
        align: 'center',
        attrs: { class: "cdmStatus" }

    },
    {
        dataField: "dateAndTime",
        text: "Last Modified Date",
        sort: true,
        formatter: Helper.completeDateFormat,
        headerStyle: { width: "12%" }
    },{
        dataField: "isDefault",
        text:"",
        sort:false,
        formatter: setDefault,
        headerStyle: { width: "10%" },
        style: (cell, row, rowIndex, colIndex) => {
            if (row.isDefault) {
            return {
                backgroundColor: '#faede7'
            };
            }
            return {
            backgroundColor: '#e5f3fe'
            };
        }
    },
    {
        dataField: "edit",
        text: "Edit",
        sort: false,
        formatter: rankFormatter,
        headerAttrs: { width: 50 },
        attrs: { width: 50, class: "EditRow" },
        events: {
            onClick: (e, column, columnIndex, row, rowIndex) => {
                console.log("Aya tou sahi")

         } 
       }
   }])
 }
```

Comment: So, I figured out that the dropdown will show if the function returning it is assigned to the formatter attribute. I had to tweak it alittle by making it conditional if the (...) button is clicked then show drop down else show (...) button.

Comment: Now I just wanted to figure out how to give that indicator in the <div> of dropdown pointing upwards. like a note

Comment: did that last part as well. this link helped me achieve the goal.                                                    [link](https://jsbin.com/fuhatiqace/1/edit?html,css,output)